# Why doesn't the ng-lightning datepicker fire a (change) event when selecting a date?

Tags: ng-lightning

I'm using Angular 9 and ng-lightning 7.  I'm trying to use the `ngl-datepicker-input` component, but I'm having trouble having it behave how I want.  The effect I'd like to achieve is to have a `save()` method be invoked EITHER:

- When a date is selected in the datepicker popup window
- When the user is **done** making changes to the input box (ie: the Angular (change) event binding for an input box)

However, it seems like the `ngl-datepicker-input` (https://ng-lightning.github.io/ng-lightning/#/components/datepickers) only provides the `(valueChange)` `EventEmitter`.  This fires when the user selects a date in the datepicker popup window (ok for me) but it also fires on every keystroke into the input box (NOT ok for me).  I don't want to `save()` until the user is done with editing.

I tried using just an ordinary `(change)` event binding on the input like below.  This works very well for any user interactions with the input box.  However, selecting a date out of the input box does not fire the `(change)` event, so I'm not able to capture those changes.

```
<ngl-datepicker-input
  format="middle-endian"
  [openOnInputClick]="false"
  [class.slds-has-error]="!model.valid"
  [(ngModel)]="checkpointDate"
  #model="ngModel">
  <input nglDatepickerInput type="text" (change)="save()">
</ngl-datepicker-input>
```

How can I either:

1. Use the `(change)` event binding on the input box, and then separately handle changes emitted by ONLY the datepicker popup window?
2. Allow selections in the datepicker popup window to also trigger a `(change)` event in the input box?